# 403 access forbidden error (forbidden) is raised on calling a controller

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

i have request mapping for the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/signupforflashsale", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    @ResponseBody
    public boolean signupForFlashsale(@RequestParam(value = "email") final String email)
    {
    ......
    }
```

I am accessing this mapping using the following URL :
http://local.test.com:9001/email

But I am getting the following error :

```
POST http://local.test.com:9001/view/EmailSignUpAddressComponentController/signupforflashsale 403 (Forbidden)jquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 f.support.ajax.f.ajaxTransport.sendjquery-1.7.2.min.js:4 f.extend.ajaxflashsale.js:8 registerForFlashSaleVM2133:1 (anonymous function)
```

the following mapping  http://local.tumi.com:9001/email call a java script function javascript:registerForFlashSale() to access the controller method signupForFlashsale using a ajax call.

This is the jsp form which includes the email value plus the two buttons.

```
<form id="FlashSaleForm" name="flashSaleForm" action="javascript:registerForFlashSale();" method="POST"><div class="ctnr-input-with-button">
        <input id="emailid" name="email" placeholder="Enter your email" type="text" value=""><button type="submit" id="signupforflashsale" class="btn btn-v-1" value="/c/flashsale">
            Submit</button>
        <a href="www.google.com"><button type="button" id="nothanksforflashsale" class="btn btn-v-1">
            No Thanks</button>
              </a>
    </div>
    <span id="responseSuccessMsg" style="display: none;">Thanks for signing up <br> Keep an eye on your email for info about our new products and deals</span>
    <span id="responseAlreadySignedUp" style="display: none;">Already signed up</span>
    <span id="responseErrorMsg" style="display:none">Thanks for signing up but there is error occured. Please try again!!!</span>
    <span id="responseInvalidEmail" style="display: none;">Invalid format. Email address must contain @-symbol and domain extension</span>

<input type="hidden" name="CSRFToken" value="9ab43f55-9580-4961-bdd7-d753e4346705">
</form>
```

Comment: mmm... at first sight, if the RequestMapping has the value "signupforflashsale", you should use this value in the url to be able to call that mapping. I don't know what it is executing but calling only http://local.test.com:9001/email, you can't access that mapping

Comment: where does your url local***/email hit? check the logs

Comment: This issue is resolved guys. There was an error related to CSRF token and that is resolved now.